# SQL dividing 2 aggregates is giving invalid Operand data type error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm using SUM and case expressions to produce 2 aggregate values, and then I want to divide the 2 figures to calculate the percentage.

I've tried casting all the statements, but I keep getting an error:

> Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Operand data type varchar is invalid for divide operator.

I'm confused that it's reading the 3rd condition as a varchar - I've tried casting it as Integer and Decimal, but receive the same error. Here's the code I'm using:

```
SELECT 
  cast(SUM(case when Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code = '99' then 1 end) as INTEGER)'Not Known'
, cast(SUM(case when Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code IS NOT NULL then 1 end)as INTEGER)'All'
, cast('Not Known'/'All' as DECIMAL (10,2)) 'Calculation'
```

I've also tried using a different approach, but this also gives the same error:

```
SELECT 
'NotKnown'
,'All'
,'NotKnown' / 'All' as 'Calculation'

(SELECT
cast(SUM(case when Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code = '99' then 1 end) as INTEGER)as 'NotKnown'
, cast(SUM(case when Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code IS NOT NULL then 1 end)as INTEGER)as 'All'

FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Spells

WHERE Discharge_Date BETWEEN '01/01/2017' AND '31/01/2017'
AND Admission_Method_National_Code LIKE '2%'
AND Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code != 'Z'

)
```

Please can anyone advise where I'm going wrong in my syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use an alias in the `SELECT` clause again in that clause.  I also don't think you need those casts.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code = '99' THEN 1 END) AS [Not Known],
    SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS [All],
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code = '99' THEN 1 END) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) /
    SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) [Calculation]
FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Spells
WHERE ...
```

Your second attempt, which is also potentially a good idea, was failing because you were referring to aliases using string literals, i.e.

```
'NotKnown' / 'All' as 'Calculation'
```

SQL Server thinks you are trying to divide strings, hence the error you were seeing.  If you want to go down the route of wrapping with a subquery, you can try the following:

```
SELECT t.[Not Known],
       t.[All],
       CAST(t.[Not Known] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / t.[All] AS [Calculation]
FROM
(
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code = '99' THEN 1 END) AS [Not Known],
        SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) AS [All],
    FROM Inpatients.vw_IP_Spells
    WHERE ...
) t
```

This has the added benefit of making the overall query less verbose and possibly easier to read.  It might also slow down the performance, but maybe you don't care about that.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen thanks for your help. The code now runs but returns a 0 figure in the Calculation field. I've cast the calculation as a decimal, but still returning just 0.00. Any idea why the calculation isn't working? The amended final line is: `cast(SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code = '99' THEN 1 END) /
  SUM(CASE WHEN Patient_Ethnic_Origin_Code IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) as DECIMAL (10,2))[Calculation]`

Comment: @Jon295087 Follow my answer and note that if you want a decimal result from dividing the two sums, you need to cast the dividend and/or the divisor as a decimal.  You were dividing two integers, and then trying to cast the result to a decimal.  That won't work.  Your hunch to use a subquery is a good one, hopefully my answer leads you in the right direction.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen many thanks, I've used the subquery approach and that's worked great. Performance isn't too bad on this dataset, so that's a bonus. My only slight doubt now is on why the decimal output is displaying to 13 decimal places, even though I've specified just 2. Do you have any suggestions what might be upsetting this? `100 - CAST(t.[NotKnown] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / t.[All] * 100 AS [Calculation]`

Comment: `DECIMAL(10,2)` only refers to the precision of the column, not necessarily to how it renders.  Casting the entire expression again should work, i.e. `CAST(100 - CAST(t.[NotKnown] AS DECIMAL(10,2)) / t.[All]*100 AS DECIMAL(10,2))`  ... but I'm not sure I have a good answer why this is needed.

Comment: @Tim_Biegeleisen - that's rendered it correctly. Many thanks again for your time and discussion